# TeamViewer special key on local and remote end not matching

Tags: keyboard, remote-desktop, remote-access, teamviewer

I am using TeamViewer 7.0.11474 to remotely control a Mac Pro from my Macbook Pro.  I occasionally find that some key strokes (likely the special keys) I type on local machine gets translated differently onto the remote machine, because within the same software some familiar  keyboard shortcut doesn't work as expected.  I am worrying perhaps there is something simple I'm missing?  Anybody knows any information about this or can suggest things to check?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure you have "Send remote Key Combinations" turned on. If it is not turned on, you may have problems sending remote combinations.

Comment: Were is this configuration?  I couldn't find it.

Comment: While your connected, there should be a little bar at the top of remote desktop screen. Pull it down with the down arrow (if needed), then go to Actions-->Send Remote Key Combinations.

Comment: I checked.  "Send Remote Key Combinations" is already checked.  But the problem still there.

Comment: I found if I type `0`, it sometimes transfers `)` to the remote computer.  Is that of any help to diagnose the problem?

Comment: Hmm... What version of TeamView are you using?

Comment: Version is mentioned in the OP.

Comment: Sorry. Didn't see that.

Comment: You are using Apple keyboards on both computers correct?

Comment: I am using the keyboard embedded to Macbook Pro on client side. The Mac Pro uses a Mac keyboard that came with the computer.

Comment: Alright. I'm out of ideas. You might want to contact Teamviewer about the issue.

Comment: Maybe guest and host use different keyboard layouts? That could be the reason for the _unexpected translations_.

Comment: I, too, have this selected but I cannot seem to send the PrtScn button.

Comment: Looks like this option was removed recently...